# Retrieve records where both field values exist in same table

Tags: sql, join, union, common-table-expression

I have table 'ReceiverDet' with column names 'ReceiverNo', and 'PartNo'. I want to retrieve all the records where 'PartNo' equals "CoC" and a user entered value (ie. "44661"). Then I want to only retrieve the records that contain both 'PartNo' values with the same 'ReceiverNo'.

I've tried UNION, JOIN and CTE and can't get any to work, though I am pretty sure CTE is the answer.

ReceiverDet Table

```
+------------+--------+
| ReceiverNo | PartNo |
+------------+--------+
| 1001       | 9173   |
+------------+--------+
| 1002       | CoC    |
+------------+--------+
| 1003       | 5432   |
+------------+--------+
| 1003       | CoC    |
+------------+--------+
| 1002       | 44661  |
+------------+--------+
```

For this example, I want my end result to be ReceiverNo "1002" since it contains both "CoC" and the user inputted value of "44661".

Answer (score 1):

If `ReceiverNo` and `PartNo` are the composite key on the table (uniquely identify a record), you can do this:

```sql
SELECT
  ReceiverNo
FROM
  ReceiverDet
WHERE
  PartNo = 'CoC'
  OR
  PartNo = @UserInput
GROUP BY
  ReceiverNo
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT PartNo) = 2;
```

Comment: I'd do `count(distinct PartNo) = 2`, just in case.

Comment: And if ReceiverNo and PartNo are not the composite key, use COUNT(DISTINCT PartNo).

Comment: Probably better to do that regardless

Comment: sql tag is meant for ISO/ANSI standards SQL not for deviated SQL dialect syntax which looks like SQL Server (MSSQL) so you should ideally remove the user variable usage from the SQL code

Comment: Thanks Tom and everyone else.